# Як правильно перекласти Organizational Enabler?

Tags: from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо Organizational Enabler в рамках проєкту "[PMBOK](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMBOK) та PM ISO українською".

Наразі є варіанти "Організаційні фактори" або "Організаційні чинники", але, здається, жоден з них не передає змісту терміна.

Подивитися оригинальний текст можна [тут](https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/organizational-enablers-projectbased-organizations-8974), [тут](https://www.pmi.org/pmbok-guide-standards/lexicon) (потрібна реєстрація) i [тут](https://www.pmi.org/pmbok-guide-standards/foundational/pmbok) (потрібно платне членство).

Тлумачення з іншого джерела:

> [ORGANIZATIONAL ENABLERS](https://www.ventureline.com/accounting-glossary/O/organizational-enablers-definition/) are the skills and knowledge, the tools and resources, and the culture of the organization that will enable it to achieve strategy.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Спроба перекладу від [Yola](/u/9) і [Sasha](/u/4):</sub>
>
> <sub>ORGANIZATIONAL ENABLERS — це вміння і знання, інструменти і ресурси, а також культура організації, що уможливлюють (роблять можливими) виконання її стратегії.</sub>

Comment: Наведіть найвідповідніші/найпотрібніші для перекладу витяги з текстів.

Comment: Тобто фактично, як я розумію, шукається короткий відповідник для словосполучення **«те, що надає можливість»**. Мені особисто не подобається [дослівний переклад «уможливлювач» від Yola](/a/6290), тож нічого іншого, окрім неточних «фактор» і «чинник», я запропонувати не можу. До ряду «фактор, чинник, …» ще можна додати «агент», але це так само неточно (хоча може допомогти запобігти якимось конотаціям, властивим словам «фактор» і «чинник», але має власні недоречні конотації).

Answer (score 1):

Можна перекласти дослівно - **організаційні уможливлювачі.**

Ось кілька прикладів вживання слова *уможливлювач*:

> - Адміністрація як надавач послуг, *уможливлювач* та добрий приклад культури підприємництва.
> - Вони вчаться страхові, великому *уможливлювачу* згубних традицій.
> - Вчитель — ​головний *уможливлювач* усіх реформ.

Answer (score 1):

[У фейсбук-групі «Український переклад»](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/3100789309956816/?comment_id=3117717144930699) пропонують «рушії організації».

Варіант від мене — «організаційні рушії». Приклади вживання словосполучення:

> Екзекутива ствердила, що секретарі та організатори відділів і новостворений Відділ продажу забезпечення є необхідними для УНСоюзу як паралельно діючі організаційні рушії. // Стаття «УНСоюз виплатить понад мільйон долярів дивіденди своїм членам», український щоденник «Свобода», ч. 8 рік CXVI, Джерзі Ситі і Ню Йорк, 14-го січня 1989, [с. 4](http://www.svoboda-news.com/arxiv/pdf/1989/Svoboda-1989-008.pdf#page=4).
>
> ---
>
> Ми вважаємо, що кооперація — це основний організаційний рушій садівництва. // [Стаття «Рушії українського садівництва» (інтерв'ю Олександра Карпенка з Дмитром Крошкою)](https://infoindustria.com.ua/rushiyi-ukrayinskogo-sadivnitstva/), журнал «Агроиндустрия», Журнал «Агроиндустрия», 05.01.2017, 06:26.